# Getting an index error when using a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write some code to parse through some arbitrary string, s, to return the longest possible string from s, in alphabetical order. I think I'm getting to the right idea, but I keep getting an IndexError when I use a for loop. Here is the code (in Python), and some explanation of where the error is coming from after:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
temp = ''
temp_len = len(temp)
longest = ''
longest_len = len(longest)
for i in range(len(s)):
    temp += s[i]
    if s[i+1] not in a[a.index(s[i]):len(a)]:
        temp = ''
    if temp_len > longest_len:
        longest = temp
print(longest)
```

The error seems to come from the first if-else statement within the loop body. Whenever I have "s[i+1]", I get an IndexError only for that line of code. It doesn't happen when I change it to "s[i]". Does anyone know the reasoning for this error? Can I not refer to indices beyond the current iteration's index of the for loop? Also, thank you in advance, and any help is appreciated.

Error message says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/edX/introduction.py", line 10, in <module>
    if s[i+1] not in a[a.index(s[i]):len(a)]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: In the last iteration you are trying to access memory that isn't allocated. Thus it is giving you an error. You have to add a special case for the last element or stop one iteration earlier.

Comment: What do you expect `s[i+1]` to return when `i` is the index of the last element?

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `i == len(s)-1`, at the end of your loop, `s[i+1]` is `s[len(s)]`, which is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

A few options you could try is to

- catch the error: `try:` and `except:`
- use `while` instead of `for`
- depending on the text you're using, `EOL` may be helpful

It would be best to experiment with a few different options, that'll improve your programming in general.